# Can't seem to import modules using __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I am going to feel like a complete idiot when someone answers this question because I know that I have done this before.

Using Python 2.7.5

I have the following file structure:

```
sandbox/
|-- fun
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- spock.py
|-- __init__.py
`-- something
    |-- blah.py
    `-- __init__.py
```

Notice that there is an `__init__.py` file at each level.  Each `__init__.py` is empty.

`spock.py` and `blah.py` are super simple.

`spock.py`

```
def helpmespock():
    print "help me spock!"
```

blah.py

```
import fun.spock

fun.spock.helpmespock()
```

Executing blah from sandbox and from sandbox/something results in the same error:

```
[me@computer sandbox]$ python something/blah.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "something/blah.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fun.spock
ImportError: No module named fun.spock
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I import `spock.py` from `blah.py`?

---

### Solved

Thanks to everyone that responded.  All of it was helpful.

Everything I did was right except for executing blah.py directly.  I added `test.py` at the top-level which imports `blah.py`.

`test.py`:

```
import something.blah

something.blah.blah()
```

So now the tree looks like this:

```
sandbox/
|-- fun
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- spock.py
|-- something
|   |-- blah.py
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- test.py
```

Executing the `test.py` gives me:

```
[sri@s6000-devel sandbox]$ python test.py
help me spock!
```

Comment: no, [sri@s6000-devel something]$ python blah.py 
  File "blah.py", line 1
    import ..fun.spock
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Still no joy.  (Python 2.7.5)

[sri@s6000-devel something]$ python blah.py 
  File "blah.py", line 1
    from .. import fun.spock
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Is the fact that there are no __init__.PYC files a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you are directly running blah.py and import cannot resolve `sandbox.fun.spock` or `fun.spock` as parent, because `__name__` is evaluated as `"__main__"`.

So, `__name__` should be `"sandbox.something.blah"` AND `sandbox` must be in path:

1. Correct sandbox/something/blah.py to import correctly:

   ```
   from ..fun import spock

   spock.helpmespock()
   ```

   or even better

   ```
   from ..fun import spock

   def do():
       spock.helpmespock()
   ```
2. Create a main to test blah (sandox/../test.py):

   ```
   import sandbox.something.blah

   sandbox.something.blah.do()
   ```

Comment: For information, reference is available about intra-package references at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 1):

You need add the sys.path

```
import os, sys                                                                  

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))
import fun.spock                                                                

fun.spock.helpmespock()
```

Comment: The python path execution for something/blah.py is sandbox/something. blah.py doesn't know the path to fun, because it is a explicit execution. 

It would be different if you create a new file (test.py) with only import something.blah in the sandbox directory. Executing this file the path is sandbox (fun and something ar known)

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: you can know the path with sys.path

Comment: Your English is very good.  I know that I've done this without manipulating sys.path before.  You are correct, importing fun.spock from sandbox works.

Answer (score 1):

try adding ".." to your path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from fun import spock

print spock.helpmespock()
```

Comment: That works too but I shouldn't have to manipulate the search path directly.  The __init__.py files are supposed to make the modules available.  right?

Comment: You're right, maybe this will be useful to us: [pythonic __init__.py](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)

Answer (score 0):

try importing in the absolute sense

```
import sandbox.fun.spock
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "some/blah.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sandbox.fun.spock
ImportError: No module named sandbox.fun.spock

Comment: Is your module inside the python path? Try positioning yourself into the directory that is parent to `sandbox`, then run the code.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  {[sri@s6000-devel ~]$ python sandbox/something/blah.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox/something/blah.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sandbox.fun.spock
ImportError: No module named sandbox.fun.spock
}

Comment: Sounds like I'm not crazy then.  What I'm doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot know if this is relevant to anyone else; but I encountered this problem because my system (Mac OSX 10.15.6) with Conda 4.8.3, the bashrc was not initializing correctly, and continously defaulted to the system python

```
# Open terminal:
python --version  # Python 3.7.7
which python  # $HOME/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
```

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
python --version  # Python 2.7.16
which python  # /usr/local/bin/python
```

As a result, my python interface was using the wrong version of python (2.7 instead of 3.7). In case that helps, check the version immediately before running the code; in my case the version was switched part way through developing.